# Django Sign Up with extra fields

Tags: django

I have expanded my SignUp form with UserCreationForm and make email activations. And all works perfect, but I don't understand how I address the new variable. 
I can't display it in a template and I do not find it in the user admin panel.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from customuser.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length= 20)   #<--my new variable 

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('reg/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'reg/signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('index')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

If I try insert ***phone*** at the html template like **{{ user.phone }}** I can't see anything. If I try add **phone** at the admin.py file like this

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import User

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    """Define admin model for custom User model with no email field."""

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'phone' ,'password',)}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
```

Error appears

```
Unknown field(s) (phone) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.
```

My custom user model

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Show us your User model (`from customuser.models import User`), does it have a `phone` field?

Comment: No, I added my custom user moodel up

Comment: First, why do you define email (that's already defined in `AbstractUser`)? Second, you should add a `phone` field to your user model, otherwise your form has nowhere to save the phone input.

Comment: I proceeded from the fact that I do not need the username field and instead I want to use the email field. I found only this method. How can I add phone field, somethig like phone = forms.CharField(max_length= 20) at my  class User(AbstractUser) ?

Comment: And you have it in your template using `{{ form.phone }}`. Can't you use it with `user.phone`?

Comment: Yes I have it in form, but I also need it in my user models

Comment: Yep, add `phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)` to your `User` model. Note: `CharField` should be imported from `django.db.models` not `django.forms`. And you can remove the `phone` field from your `SignupForm` since you already include it via the `fields` property in `Meta`.

Comment: Perfect!! It's work. Now I can see my phone fields at user admin panel. But when I try show phone in user profile template {{ user.phone }} it still does't work.

Comment: You need to show us the code for the view and template where you use `{{user.phone}}`. Is the `user` context variable correctly defined in your view?

Comment: Where in your view do you define the `user` variable? If you use `{{user}}` in your template, you must define it somewhere first. Try `return render(request, 'user/profile.html', context={'user': self.request.user})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a `Form` and a `Model` in Django. A `Form` (also a `ModelForm`) is just what it says, a Django representation of the HTML form you present to the user. It's only purpose is to make it easy to submit data via a POST request.

The form cannot just save to the database, unless there's an underlying model. With a plain `Form`, you would have to do this in your view handling the POST request:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        my_model = MyModel(param1=form.cleaned_data['param1'], ...)
        my_model.save()
        return redirect(success_url)
    ...
```

As you can see, both the Model and the Form must have corresponding fields (in the example above `param1`, etc...).

To make it easier to create forms for a model, Django gives you a `ModelForm`, where the form 'knows' how to save the underlying model, so you can do:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        my_model = form.save()
        ...
```

In this case the form will map the form fields to the model fields, so only those model fields that exist on the model can be saved. Your form could contain 5 extra fields not defined on the model, still validate, but nothing happens with those fields when you save the form, because the model doesn't have them.

Full documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: my urls is `url(r'^profile/$', views.user_profile)`

Comment: my views is `@login_required
def user_profile(request):    
    return render(request, 'client/profile.html')`

Comment: And in my settings.py  `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/'`. And 
for this reason I can't transfer pk or other varriables at request.